# How to Add/Remove select option from 1 drop down on selection of other dropdown option

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, dropdown, html-select

Suppose I have 2 dropdowns. My requirement is, On selection of an option in first dropdown that option should be removed from other dropdown and on unselection of that option from the first dropdown that option should be available in other dropdown for selecion.

Comment: Give all linked options a similar id, like 'option_1_left' and 'option_1_right'. In the onchange event on your select, use the .selectedIndex of the dropdown to get the correct option. (Or use an onclick handler on options instead and use event.target). Once your have the selected option, get its id, replace 'left' by 'right'. Then you have the id of the option you should remove from the other dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written the following JavaScript to solve above problem, just give your dropdowns a common class like "importance" here and use this code:

```
            var j$importance = j$(".importance");

            j$importance.on("change", function () {

                var select = this,
                    selected = j$("option:selected", this).text();

                var currentUnselectedValues = [];

                j$('option', this).each(function() { 

                    currentUnselectedValues.push( j$(this).text());
                });

                j$importance.each(function (_, el) {

                    for(i=0; i<currentUnselectedValues.length; i++){

                       var exist = false;

                       j$('option', el).each(function(_, elm) { 

                           if(currentUnselectedValues[i] === j$(elm).text()){

                               exist = true;
                           }
                       });

                       if(exist === false){

                          j$(el).append('<option value="' + currentUnselectedValues[i] + '">' + currentUnselectedValues[i] + '</option>');
                       }
                    }

                    if (el !== select) {
                        j$("option", el).each(function (_, el) {
                            var j$el = j$(el);
                            if (j$el.text() === selected && j$el.text() != '--None--') {
                                j$el.remove();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

             });
```